# WP8 Company Hub and AddPackageAsync()

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am in the process of developing and testing a company hub on the WP8 emulator and using InstallationManager.AddPackageAsync() to install packages that the hub app has downloaded. At the moment the various installations that I am testing fail to install with a generic error. I know that the packages have been downloaded correctly as I can pull them off the device and then use xapdeploy to successfully deploy them to the emulator.

Do the packages that you are installing need to be signed and the application enrolment token installed on the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you successfully enrolled your emulator to your MDM server. Company Hub will work only on enrolled devices

Edit: AFAIK also the XAP packages need to be resigned with your certificate.

Comment: that is pretty much exactly the answer I was looking for. Now that I know you need to enrol the emulator I can do that and carry on. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did this work?  I have a similar problem with a WP8 device, but it is definitely enrolled